# Is this set countable? Verify me. Simple question. Basic set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Basic set theory question, I think I have the answer but I would like someone to double check it please.

let $R$ be an equivalence relation defined on $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ such that:

$R=\{(f,g)\in \mathbb N^{\mathbb N} | \exists b \in \mathbb N. \forall n>b. f(n)=g(n)\}$

Basically, $fRg$ if and only if after  certain $b$, $f(n)=g(n)$ for all $n>b$.

let $h \in \mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$, $h(n)=n^2$.

What is the $|[h]|$? (meaning the cardinality of the equivalence class of $h$).

**My answer**

I think that this set is not countable. Let look for example at the function $k(n)=n$ while $n<5$ and $k(n)=n^2$ for $5 \leq n$.

$k$ is related to $h$. But when you think about it, I didn't have to take $k(n)=n$, I could choose any function I like, since there is an uncountable number of functions from the natural numbers to the natural numbers, I have uncountable many options for $k$.

So the cardinality of the equivalence class of $h$ is $\aleph1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wrong, on two accounts really.

1. The fact that the equivalence class is not countable doesn't mean its size is $\aleph_1$, unless you assume $\sf CH$ or so.
2. $|[h]|$ is in fact countable. Note that if $(f,h)\in R$ then as a subset of $\Bbb{N\times N}$, the symmetric difference $f\mathop{\triangle} h$ is finite. How many of those are there?

Comment: if I understood the question correctly, the answer is $\aleph_0$

Comment: Yes. And you should underscore the index.

Comment: Also, as far as I know, we assume ZFC in TAU.

Comment: I will have to ask your superiors on Friday.

Answer (score 2):

No, $|[h]|$ is countably infinite. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let

$$H_n=\left\{f\in\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}:f(k)=h(k)\text{ for all }k\ge n\right\}\;;$$

then $[h]=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}H_n$, and each set $H_n$ is countable. In fact there is a very natural bijection between $H_n$ and $\Bbb N^n$.

By the way, uncountability of $|[h]|$ does not imply that its cardinality **is** $\aleph_1$, but only that its cardinality is **at least** $\aleph_1$.

Comment: Very well made argument. But why is every $H_n$ countable? Like, I'd like to know what I did wrong, because I don't see the flaw in my logic and I'd like someone to point it out, so I could learn.

Comment: @Oria: In your example your $k$ comes from $H_5$. There is a bijection between $H_5$ and $\Bbb N^5$; specifically, $k$ corresponds to $\langle k(0),k(1),k(2),k(3),k(4)\rangle$. And it’s a basic fact of cardinality that $\Bbb N^n$ is countable for each $n\in\Bbb N$.